# JMeter + Maven: how to send test result data to Grafana

Tags: maven, jmeter, influxdb, grafana, jmeter-maven-plugin

I use have JMeter tests run by [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin).

Previously I used JMeter + InfluxDB + Grafana, but what should I do now in the case when I run my JMeter test by [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin)?
How can I send test result data to [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana)?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener)

1. Add Backend Listener to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
2. Choose `org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.InfluxdbBackendListenerClient` from the "Backend Listener Implementation" dropdown
3. Point the Backend Listener to your own InfluxDB installation via `influxdbUrl` parameter

   [image: JMeter InfluxDB]

   Other parameters can be left as they are.
4. That's it, given InfluxDB is up and running and you have configured the Dashboard (you can use [this one](https://grafana.com/dashboards/1152) as an example) - you should be seeing the metrics in Grafana as your test goes.

References:

- [JMeter: Real Time Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)

Comment: thanks! To have ability to use Grafana dashboard mentioned on p.4 - this action is required: "Download theJMeter-InfluxBD-Writer and paste the jar into the /lib/ext". 
How can I do that with Maven?